# Apollo link how to decorate response data to have error inside data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

Bit new to front-end stack, from Apollo documentation I can't figure out myself how to do below.

I am trying to wrap errors also into the response data. So then I will have data.data and data.error as response.

```js
export const wrapDataLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // not sure how I access data and erorrs both here
  return forward(operation);
});
```

Btw I already has an onError link to handle errors.

```js
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      for (const err of graphQLErrors) {
        // some logic here for auth errors, rest just forward(operation);
      }
    }
  });
```

I am using "@apollo/client": "3.7.1" and "apollo-link-rest": "0.9.0-rc.2",